# How to find a separable decomposition for $|\Psi^+\rangle\!\langle\Psi^+|+|\Phi^+\rangle\!\langle\Phi^+|$?

Tags: entanglement, density-matrix

The state 
$$ \frac{1}{2}\left(| \phi^+ \rangle \langle \phi^+ | + | \psi^+ \rangle \langle \psi^+ | \right) $$

where 
$$ | \phi^+ \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt2} \left(|00 \rangle + | 11 \rangle \right) $$
$$ | \psi^+ \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt2} \left(|01 \rangle + | 10 \rangle \right) $$

By PPT criteria, we know this is a separable state. If I wanted to find what is the mixture of separable states that form this, how would I go about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would start by writing this as a matrix, and recognising how it can be written in terms of Pauli matrices:
$$
\frac14\left(\begin{array}{cccc} 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{array}\right)=\frac14(\mathbb{I}\otimes\mathbb{I}+X\otimes X)
$$
From here, I don't have a completely formulaic approach for how you do it. But, in this instance, I wrote
$$
=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\mathbb{I}+X}{2}\otimes \frac{\mathbb{I}+X}{2}+\frac{\mathbb{I}-X}{2}\otimes \frac{\mathbb{I}-X}{2}\right).
$$
Now you can see that each of the terms in the tensor product is a separable state. Specifically,
$$
(|++\rangle\langle ++|+|--\rangle\langle --|)/2
$$

One approach that I suppose I might have taken is to recognise the separable, diagonal basis of $X\otimes X$, and decompose $\mathbb{I}\otimes\mathbb{I}$ in the same basis:
$$
\frac{1}{4}(|++\rangle\langle ++|+|+-\rangle\langle +-|+|-+\rangle\langle -+|+|--\rangle\langle --|)+\frac{1}{4}(|++\rangle\langle ++|-|+-\rangle\langle +-|-|-+\rangle\langle -+|+|--\rangle\langle --|),
$$
which inevitably leads to that result.

Comment: Just want to confirm, unlike a 1 qubit system where I/2 is the only state that is diagonal in multiple bases, in a 2 qubit system a state can be diagonal in multiple bases?

Comment: Yes, because that is a result of degeneracy/multiplicity. The larger the space, the more opportunity there is for that.

Comment: Given that deciding separability is a computationally hard problem, it is not surprising that you do not have an algorithmic way to do it.